# Strange issue when retrieving data from my database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

When reading data from a table, one of my numerical values returns as a -1, rather than a value given by the user.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;database=new_project;port=3306;password=********;")
        conn.Open()
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM students;", conn)
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim dataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "students")
        Dim dataTable As DataTable = dataSet.Tables("students")
        For x As Integer = 0 To dataTable.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim newStudent As New Student
            newStudent.intIDNum = dataTable.Rows(x).Item("idNumber")
            newStudent.strFirstName = dataTable.Rows(x).Item("firstName")
            newStudent.strLastName = dataTable.Rows(x).Item("lastName")
            newStudent.chrGender = dataTable.Rows(x).Item("gender")
            newStudent.dateDOB = dataTable.Rows(x).Item("dateOfBirth")
            newStudent.intAge = CInt(Today.Year - newStudent.dateDOB.Year)
            newStudent.intYearGroup = dataTable.Rows(x).Item("yearGroup")
            newStudent.intSkillLevel = dataTable.Rows(x).Item("skillLevel")
            studentList.Add(newStudent)
            lstStudents.Items.Add(newStudent.nameConcat(newStudent.strFirstName, newStudent.strLastName))
        Next
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

When reading the value "skillLevel", it should read between 1 and 4, but instead it reads a -1. This hasn't occurred with any data added directly to the database through MySQL, but when using the method in my program, it seems this issue appears.

```
Dim newStudent As New Student
        newStudent.strFirstName = txtForename.Text
        newStudent.strLastName = txtSurname.Text
        newStudent.dateDOB = dtpStudentDOB.Value
        If rdbMale.Checked = True Then
            newStudent.chrGender = "M"
        Else
            newStudent.chrGender = "F"
        End If
        newStudent.intAge = newStudent.calcAge(dtpStudentDOB.Value)
        newStudent.intSkillLevel = cmbSkillLevel.SelectedItem
        newStudent.intYearGroup = cmbYearGroup.SelectedItem
        newStudent.intIDNum = CInt(txtStudentID.Text)
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;database=new_project;port=3306;password=********;")
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim command As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
            command.Connection = conn
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES(@IdNumber, @firstName, @lastName, @gender, @dateOfBirth, @yearGroup, @skillLevel);"
            command.Prepare()
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdNumber", newStudent.intIDNum)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", newStudent.strFirstName)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", newStudent.strLastName)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", newStudent.chrGender)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfBirth", newStudent.dateDOB)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearGroup", newStudent.intYearGroup)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skillLevel", newStudent.intSkillLevel)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
```

This is the section of code where a student is added to the system. What exactly could be causing this error to appear?

For reference, the main form I add in the data uses an enumeration:

```
Private Enum SkillLevels As Integer
    One = 1
    Two = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
End Enum
```

And then I link it to the dropdown: `cmbSkillLevel.DataSource = System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(SkillLevels))`

Comment: I think you need `newStudent.intSkillLevel = cmbSkillLevel.SelectedItem.Value`. `SelectedItem` is an object, so maybe  VB.NET is implicitly casting it and giving you an unreliable value? You can find out easily enough by popping up a message box with `newStudent.intSkillLevel = cmbSkillLevel.SelectedItem` and `newStudent.intSkillLevel = cmbSkillLevel.SelectedItem.Value`.

Comment: I tried using `cmbSkillLevel.SelectedValue` but the problem persists. It only occurs if I close my program and then reopen it, however.

Comment: What is the database side type of the skillLevel column?  Assuming its an integer type have you tried passing command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skillLevel", CInt(newStudent.intSkillLevel)) ?

Comment: This also doesn't appear to work. On the database side, skillLevel is a TINYINT type.

Comment: Does explicitly using command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skillLevel", 3) work?

Comment: Your TINYINT must be SIGNED (the default) if you have -1 in there -> try casting to SByte which is the matching .Net type.

Comment: The explicit command seems to have the same issue. When the program is loaded, the system reads it as -1 again. I also tried casting to SByte: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skillLevel", SByte.Parse(newStudent.intSkillLevel.ToString()))` But the same issue has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had misinterpreted @tolanj's comments. It appears that when loading my data, the system couldn't read my skillLevel column. To fix it, I changed `newStudent.intSkillLevel = row.Item("skillLevel")` to `newStudent.intSkillLevel = SByte.Parse(row.Item("skillLevel"))`.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious possibility is that no selection was made in the SKILL-LEVEL dropdown and that is why you are getting -1, you can check if a selection has been made in the dropdown by ensuring it is not -1

For example your skills drop down may look like this

```
<select id="SkillLevel">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">Low</option>
  <option value="2">Medium</option>
  <option value="3">High</option>
  <option value="4">Very-High</option>
</select>
```

If no selection is made the default value returned will be zero (0)
And you can check for valid values by looking for returned values > 0

As far as I can remember if you omit the selected="selected" then the returned value will be -1

Comment: The dropdown box doesn't have a zero option. The design consists of the four options and nothing else. Let me add in the details in the question instead.

Comment: Regardless of whether it has an option with zero or not, when NO selection is made the return value is ALWAYS -1 therefore it means that the form was submitted before a skill level was submitted.